# Negating Func<T, bool> in lambda expression

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
Func<T, bool> expr = x => x.Prop != 1;

somelist = somelist.Where(expr);
```

So far so good. But I would like to negate `expr` like this:

```
somelist = somelist.Where(!expr);
```

Which result in a compile error: `Cannot apply ! operator to operand of type Func<T, bool>`.

Do I have to create another expression variable for this?

```
Func<T, bool> expr2 = x => x.Prop == 1;
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
Func<T, bool> expr = x => x.Prop != 1;

Func<T, bool> negativeExpr = value => !expr(value);
```

or

```
somelist = somelist.Where(value => !expr(value));
```

When using expression trees the following will do the trick:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr = x => x.Prop != 1;

var negativeExpr = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
    Expression.Not(expr.Body), 
    expr.Parameters);

somelist = somelist.Where(negativeExpr);
```

To make your life easier, you can create the following extension methods:

```
public static Func<T, bool> Not<T>(
    this Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return value => !predicate(value);
}

public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Not<T>(
    this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr)
{
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.Not(expr.Body), 
        expr.Parameters);
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
somelist = somelist.Where(expr.Not());
```

Answer (score 19):

I'm just going to throw this out there as a *silly* answer. Just to be clear: I would not do this, and I do not recommend that anyone does this. :)

I kind of wanted to see if it was possible to get the `somelist.Where(!expr)` syntax or something like it.

Well I succeeded, and I hate myself.

```
var expr = N.egatable<MyClass>(x => x.Prop != 1);
somelist = someList.Where(!expr);
```

The `N.egatable` was just a small convenience syntax helper and largely unnecessary (EDIT: I *wanted* to avoid having to explicitly define `MyClass` or somehow make the instantiation of the object wrapper hidden, but couldn't quite get there and thought maybe someone would have a better idea):

```
public static class N
{
    public static Negator<T> egatable<T>(Func<T, bool> underlyingFunction)
    {
        return new Negator<T>(underlyingFunction);
    }
}
```

`Negator<T>` is where the real "magic" happens:

```
public class Negator<T>
{
    private Func<T, bool> UnderlyingFunction;

    public Negator(Func<T, bool> underlyingFunction)
    {
        this.UnderlyingFunction = underlyingFunction;
    }

    public static implicit operator Func<T, bool>(Negator<T> neg)
    {
        return v => neg.UnderlyingFunction(v);
    }

    public static Negator<T> operator !(Negator<T> neg)
    {
        return new Negator<T>(v => !neg.UnderlyingFunction(v));
    }
}
```

First the `!` operator overload performs the function negation (just as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18511814/1269654)), then the implicit conversion operator to `Func<T, bool>` lets it pass in to the `Where` extension method.

Perhaps very silly is you can keep flipping it back and forth like this:

```
somelist = someList.Where(!!expr);
somelist = someList.Where(!!!expr);
somelist = someList.Where(!!!!expr);
somelist = someList.Where(!!!!!expr);
somelist = someList.Where(!!!!!!expr); //oh my what
```

So again... please don't do this. :) Definitely stick to the proper/sane way of doing things as in Steven's answer.

EDIT: Here's an implementation using expressions which works the exact same way in terms of syntax usage. Not sure if it's "correct", and haven't tested it against Entity Framework:

```
public class ExpressionNegator<T>
{
    private Expression<Func<T, bool>> UnderlyingExpression;

    public ExpressionNegator(Expression<Func<T, bool>> underlyingExpression)
    {
        this.UnderlyingExpression = underlyingExpression;
    }

    public static implicit operator Func<T, bool>(ExpressionNegator<T> neg)
    {
        return neg.UnderlyingExpression.Compile();
    }

    public static implicit operator Expression<Func<T, bool>>(ExpressionNegator<T> neg)
    {
        return neg.UnderlyingExpression;
    }

    public static ExpressionNegator<T> operator !(ExpressionNegator<T> neg)
    {
        var originalExpression = neg.UnderlyingExpression;
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> negatedExpression = originalExpression.Update(
            Expression.Not(originalExpression.Body), 
            originalExpression.Parameters);
        return new ExpressionNegator<T>(negatedExpression);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to torture you more because I know this will likely eat at you until you get it to work too (I've been there). I wonder if you could get it to work with a `Expression<Func<T, bool>>` too to make it work with Linq2Entities providers like Entity Framework.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: I could probably do it with expressions, but I don't know if it would translate to compatible _runtime_ execution for entities (I suppose it _might_, after all, what's a few extra negations to an SQL query?). Maybe in my spare time I'll give it a shot.

Comment: If you want to transform a lambda into its opposite, you can simply write, with variable `Expression<Func<T, bool>> originalLambda`, `Expression<Func<T, bool>> negatedLambda = originalLambda.Update(Expression.Not(originalLambda.Body), originalLambda.Parameters);`

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: I added a naive implementation with expressions. I tested against a local list, but not against Entity Framework. Feel free to give it a shot and let us know if it works! Jean Hominal, thanks for the sample code.

Comment: Here's another idea that is much easier: Create a `Not` extension method. For instance: `public static Func<T, bool> Not(this Func<T, bool> pr) { return v => !pr(v); }`. Now you can do: `someList.Where(expr.Not())`, `someList.Where(expr.Not().Not())`, etc.

Comment: @Steven: That's a pretty great idea too! I don't know if I'd apply it in my answer here though as I _strictly_ wanted to achieve the `someList.Where(!expr)` syntax. Only major problem I see with it is that it flips the C# paradigm where the syntactical "nots" come first in the form of prefixed exclamation marks. We read the code as "not <expression>", not as "expression not". (Although, it might read well for maybe some rebellious, rude code: "YouAreSoCool == true... NOT!")

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: I do like your effort and like it when people do crazy trickery with the language. And I especially like it when this code is done in production, NOT!!! :P